# example of operator -> overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to get an example for overloading "->". As per a tutorial, signature would be A::operator->() to reflect a->b.

how does the function identify which member is to be operated on?

i would assume it could return pointer to class, object or a reference. what are the point of cautions for this,  e.g. handling of smart pointer attributes etc.

Comment: Could you be more precise with the last paragraph?

Comment: The `operator->()` implementation doesn't care about what member is being operated on; it'll just return a `T*`, and the code will compile if `T` contains a member named `b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
class PointerObject
{
public:
    PointerObject(T* p)
        : _p(p)
    {}

    T* operator ->()
    {
        return _p;
    }

private:
    T* _p;
};

struct A
{
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    PointerObject<A> po(&a);
    po->x = 1;
    po->y = 1;
}
```